# Installation of EclipseFP on Eclipse Luna (Mac OS X Yosemite)

Tags: eclipse, macos, haskell, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-fp

I'm trying to get EclipseFP (Haskell support, but the original coder stopped maintaining it last month) working on my iMac but everything seems to fail constantly. I've been debugging this for hours now and like most other Haskell stuff there isn't much decent support out there regarding the installation of such tools. I haven't even written a single line of Haskell code yet (apart from some playing around in GHC/GHCI which surprisingly did work)!

I've tried so many things already, different libraries, different solutions, different versions etc. But it seems that everything that has to do with haskell support is just one big clutter of confusion for me and nothing seems to point me in an apparent direction which bothers me since I am an experienced programmer and dealing with command line interfaces, tools and dependencies isn't unknown to me on all sort of platforms for years now.

Even the most relevant topics on StackOverflow or other knowledgebases just won't cut it regarding this topic and I'm starting to feel like dropping the entire Haskell language and just use something which does play nice with the system without such troubles since it is already such a pain in the ass to get the most basic development tools to work, let alone the coding itself...

The things I got:

- Mac OSX Yosmite
- GHC
- GHCI
- Cabal (repository)
- Eclipse Luna

I've installed EclipseFP using the [install instructions](http://eclipsefp.github.io/install.html) which worked out all great. At this point I thought it would just all work without any problems as the plugin installs just fine...

Well, that was not the case of course. I've restarted Eclipse as it requested after installing new plugins. Here is where the trouble begun..

In the following steps I would have to open the Haskell Perspective in Eclipse. Well... guess what.. there was none! After strolling the web I found out that it might have compatibility issues with the old JDK 1.6 which was installed by default on MacOSX. No worries.. I've downloaded Java JDK 1.8, set it up in Eclipse, restarted it. And there the item "Haskell perpective" showed up in the list.

After clicking that, and thinking my troubles were over (and I could finally start coding!) nothing happend! I've searched around for a while and found the Eclipse error console which until this day gives me nothing more than:

```
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui (459).

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui was unable to load class net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.HaskellPerspective.
```

Of course I have tried solving this issue and came across some dependencies which needed to be installed using cabal (BuildWrapper, Scion-Browser and some other essentials). After doing so I still have the same problem and I have no idea where to look for. The only information I can really find are topics which are more than 3/4 years old which share 0 relevance to my exact problem.

I could paste the Java stacktrace here as well which came with the error message, but it doesn't show much useful information anyway other than just basic crashing.

I hope someone can help me  because I would really like to start coding now for a change instead of wasting hours on getting my basic development framework/IDE set up.

Long story short; I'd like to code some Haskell in Eclipse but the development tools just won't install and/or work properly without any notable errors or directions to look for.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: `!STACK 0
  5 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.HaskellUIPlugin.start() of bundle net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.
  6         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
  7         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
  8         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
  9 /bin/bash: NTRY: command not found`

This is what I can see however I have no clue what could be wrong.

Comment: The log file you pointed out is the exact same as the console output in Eclipse. The only line which makes sense where errors are coming from seems to be the "NTRY: command not found" (shouldn't it be ENTRY? this is what the log shows).

Comment: Are you sure it's not a PATH issue? See the second question in the faq at http://eclipsefp.github.io/faq.html.

Comment: JP Moresmau, thank you for your contribution however. I already found that as well. This is my path:

`$ echo $PATH
/app/halcyon:/app/bin:/app/usr/bin:/app/ghc/bin:/app/cabal/bin:/app/sandbox/bin:/app/sandbox/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
`

I think it should be correct as I can't see anything weird here.